# iteration in foreach

Tags: php, html, foreach

```
foreach($tests as $i => $test){

  if ($test->getNumber() == 2) {
      echo $i . $getName() ;
  } else {
     $i--;
  }

}
```

for example:

```
number | name
    1  | aaa
    2  | bbb
    1  | ccc
    2  | vvv
    2  | ccc
```

show me:

```
   $i $name
    2 bbb
    4 vvv
    5 ccc
```

instead of:

```
   $i $name
    1 bbb
    2 vvv
    3 ccc
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: i'm not sure what your loop is trying to do....

Comment: what do you want to do ? can you add the $tests array ?

Comment: what's the use of decrementing $i?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beacuse foreach is returning you the index of $test inside $tests array so your $tests array is:

```
$tests[0] => 1 aaa
$tests[1] => 2 bbb
$tests[2] => 1 ccc
$tests[3] => 2 vvv
$tests[4] => 2 ccc
```

$i which is rewritten each iteartion by foreach statement.

Try this (using another counter):

```
$j = 0;
foreach($tests as $i => $test){
  if ($test->getNumber() == 2) {
        $j++;
      echo $j . $getName() ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are trying to do:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($tests as $key => $test){
  if ($test->getNumber() == 2) {
    echo ++$i . $getName() ;
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `$key`...

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in `$i--` as it's overwritten in the loop.

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($tests as $i => $test){
    if ($test->getNumber() == 2) {
        ++$counter;
        echo $counter . $getName() ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are printing the number from the array, rather than creating new numbering.

Untested but should work.

```
foreach($tests as $i => $test){
  $num = '0';
  if ($test->getNumber() == 2) {
      echo $num . $getName() ;
      $num++;
  } else {
     $i--;
  }

}
```

Comment: J0HN is correct actually.  There is no need for your else statement.

Comment: Yeah.  I'm gonna stop doing this while I'm at work.  Haha.

Comment: Why do you initialize $num as a string? And also, $num will be reset at every iteration of foreach... And $i-- still makes no sense.